# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function in aspx web page with master page but it is working with basic html page

Tags: highcharts

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
     <script src="../Content/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/js/helpers/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/js/helpers/exporting.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                $('#chart1').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'bar'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'data Utilization'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Data']
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 24,
                        tickInterval: 2,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Working hours'
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        reversed: true
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            stacking: 'normal'
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 's',
                        data: [5]
                    }, {
                        name: 'x',
                        data: [2]
                    }, {
                        name: 'v',
                        data: [3]
                    }]
                });

            }
    </script>
      <script src="../Content/js/helpers/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/js/helpers/exporting.js"></script>
 <div id="chart1" style="padding: 10px; height: 300px; overflow: auto;" ></div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you format your code, describe yours differents files and where you call your window.onload ?

Comment: Why are you including the highcharts.js twice? before and after your code?

Answer (score 2):

You are loading `../Content/js/helpers/highcharts.js` and `../Content/js/helpers/exporting.js` two times - before and after `window.onload` function. That may cause JS to go crazy.

Comment: i have removed js files which i included and tried still i am facing